# Async access to School

Tags: c#, async-await

I have this class with two public async methods, which also calls some private methods that are async.

**Here's the class:**

```
public class AggregatedDataService
{
    public IPrincipal User
    {
        get { return HttpContext.Current.User; }
    }

    public object SessionToken { get { return HttpContext.Current.Session["session_token"]; } }
    private static string baseUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["baseURI"];
    private readonly ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    public async Task<OrganizationAggregatedInfo> GetOrganizationAggregatedInfo(int organizationId)
    {
        var organization = await GetOrganization(organizationId);
        var organizationContact = await GetOrganizationContact(organization.ID);
        var associations = await GetOrganizationAssociations(organization.ID);

        return new OrganizationAggregatedInfo(organization.Name, organization.Address, organizationContact,
            associations);
    }

    public async Task<SchoolAggregatedInfo> GetSchoolAggreagtedInfo(int schoolId)
    {
        if(schoolId < 1)
            return null;

        var school = await GetSchool(schoolId);
        if (school == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        var getSchoolAddressTask = GetSchoolAddress(schoolId); 
        var getMemberSchoolsTask = GetMemberSchools(schoolId);
        var getSchoolCurriculumTask = GetSchoolCurriculum(schoolId);
        var getSchoolFacilitiesTask = GetSchoolFacilities(schoolId);
        var getSchoolAssociationsTask = GetSchoolAssociations(schoolId);
        var getSchoolAcreditationsTask = GetSchoolAcreditations(schoolId);
        var getGovernanceStructureTask = GetGovernanceStructure(schoolId);

        await Task.WhenAll(getSchoolAddressTask, getMemberSchoolsTask, getSchoolCurriculumTask,
                getSchoolFacilitiesTask, getSchoolAssociationsTask, getSchoolAcreditationsTask,
                getGovernanceStructureTask);

        var schoolAddress = getSchoolAddressTask.Result;
        var memberSchools = getMemberSchoolsTask.Result; 
        //var teacherInfo = await GetTeacherInformation(schoolAddress.SchoolID);
        var curriculum = getSchoolCurriculumTask.Result;
        var facilities = getSchoolFacilitiesTask.Result;
        var associations = getSchoolAssociationsTask.Result;
        var accreditations = getSchoolAcreditationsTask.Result;
        var governanceStructure = getGovernanceStructureTask.Result; 

        SchoolContactReadView contact = null;

        if (schoolAddress != null)
        {
            if (schoolAddress.SchoolContact != null)
                contact = SchoolContactReadView.ShowSchoolContactView(schoolAddress.SchoolContact);
        }

        var schoolAggregateInfo = new SchoolAggregatedInfo
        {
            Name = school.Name,
            Address = school.Address,
            MemberSchoolsCount = memberSchools.Count(),
            GovernanceStructure = governanceStructure,
            Accreditations = accreditations.ToList(),
            Associations = associations.ToList(),
            Contact = contact,
            Curriculum = curriculum,
            Facilities = facilities.ToList()
        };

        return schoolAggregateInfo;
    }

    private async Task<List<OrganizationAssociationReadView>> GetOrganizationAssociations(int organizationId)
    {
        List<OrganizationAssociationReadView> associations = new List<OrganizationAssociationReadView>();

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            if (SessionToken != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (ValidateToken(client).IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/organization/associations/" + organizationId);
                        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        {
                            //create list of associations
                            var contentResult = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<OrganizationAssociation>>();
                            associations = contentResult.Select(OrganizationAssociationReadView.MapFrom).ToList();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            _log.Error("API Error Reason: " + response.ReasonPhrase);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception sd)
                {
                    _log.Error("Error displaying Associations ", sd);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _log.Info("User not logged-in.");
            }
        }

        return associations;
    }

    private async Task<OrganizationContactReadView> GetOrganizationContact(int organizationId)
    {
        OrganizationContactReadView organizationContact = null;

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            if (SessionToken != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (ValidateToken(client).IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/organization/contact/" + organizationId);
                        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        {
                            var contentResult = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<OrganizationContact>();
                            var organizationContactReadView = OrganizationContactReadView.MapFrom(contentResult);

                            organizationContact = organizationContactReadView;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            _log.Error("API Error Reason: " + response.ReasonPhrase);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception sd)
                {
                    _log.Error("Error displaying Organization Contact Information ", sd);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _log.Info("User not logged-in.");
            }
        }

        return organizationContact;
    }

    private async Task<OrganizationReadView> GetOrganization(int organizationId)
    {
        OrganizationReadView organization = null;

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            if (SessionToken != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (ValidateToken(client).IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/organization/getbyid/" + organizationId);
                        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        {
                            var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Organization>();
                            var organisationReadView = OrganizationReadView.MapFrom(responseContent);
                            organization = organisationReadView;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //make sure the server has this installed and supports c# 6
                            //_log.Info($"Failed to get organization because the hhtp response was not OK. Response code is {response.StatusCode.ToString()}");
                            _log.Info("Failed to get organization because the hhtp response was not OK. Response code is " + response.StatusCode);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //make sure the server has this installed and supports c# 6
                    //_log.Error($"An error occured while trying to retrieve Organization for user {User.Identity.Name}. Exception message: {ex.Message}");
                    _log.Error("An error occured while trying to retrieve Organization for user" +
                               User.Identity.Name + ". Exception message: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _log.Info("User not logged-in.");
            }

            return organization;
        }
    }

    private async Task<GovernanceStructureReadView> GetGovernanceStructure(int schoolId)
    {
        GovernanceStructureReadView governanceStructureReadView = new GovernanceStructureReadView();
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            if (SessionToken != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (ValidateToken(client).IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var response = await client.GetAsync("api/school/getgovernancestructure/" + schoolId);
                        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        {
                            var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<GovernanceStructure>();
                            governanceStructureReadView =
                                GovernanceStructureReadView.ShowGovernanceStructureView(responseContent);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            _log.Error("API Error Reason: " + response.ReasonPhrase);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception sd)
                {
                    _log.Error("Error displaying Governance Structure ", sd);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _log.Info("User not logged-in.");
            }
        }
        return governanceStructureReadView;
    }

    private async Task<IEnumerable<AccreditationReadView>>  GetSchoolAcreditations(int schoolId)
    {
        IEnumerable<AccreditationReadView> accreditationReadViews = new List<AccreditationReadView>();
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            if (SessionToken != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (ValidateToken(client).IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        HttpResponseMessage response =
                            await client.GetAsync("api/school/accreditationsbyschool/" + schoolId);
                        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        {
                            var accreditations = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Accreditation>>();
                            accreditationReadViews =
                                accreditations.Select(AccreditationReadView.ShowAccreditationView);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            _log.Error("API Error Veiwing Accreditations : " + response.ReasonPhrase);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception sd)
                {
                    _log.Error("Error displaying Accreditations ", sd);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _log.Info("User not logged-in.");
            }
        }
        return accreditationReadViews;
    }

    private async Task<IEnumerable<AssociationReadView>> GetSchoolAssociations(int schoolId)
    {
        List<AssociationReadView> associationReadViews = new List<AssociationReadView>();
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            if (SessionToken != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (ValidateToken(client).IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/school/associationsbyschool/" + schoolId);
                        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        {
                            List<Association> associations = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Association>>();
                            associationReadViews =
                                associations.Select(AssociationReadView.ShowAssociationView).ToList();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            _log.Error("API Error Reason: " + response.ReasonPhrase);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception sd)
                {
                    _log.Error("Error displaying Associations ", sd);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _log.Info("User not logged-in.");
            }
        }
        return associationReadViews;
    }

    private async Task<IEnumerable<SchoolFacilityReadView>> GetSchoolFacilities(int schoolId)
    {
        IEnumerable<SchoolFacilityReadView> schoolFacilityReadViews = new List<SchoolFacilityReadView>();
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            if (SessionToken != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (ValidateToken(client).IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/school/facilities/" + schoolId);
                        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        {
                            var schoolFacilities = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<SchoolFacility>>();
                            schoolFacilityReadViews = schoolFacilities.Select(SchoolFacilityReadView.ShowSchoolFacilityView);}
                        else
                        {
                            _log.Error("API Error Reason: " + response.ReasonPhrase);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception sd)
                {
                    _log.Error("Error displaying School Facilities ", sd);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _log.Info("User not logged-in.");
            }
        }
        return schoolFacilityReadViews;
    }

    private async Task<SchoolCurriculumReadView> GetSchoolCurriculum(int schoolId)
    {
        SchoolCurriculumReadView schoolCurriculumReadView = new SchoolCurriculumReadView();
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            if (SessionToken != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (ValidateToken(client).IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/school/getcurricula/" + schoolId);
                        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        {
                            SchoolCurriculumInformation schoolCurriculumInformation =
                                await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<SchoolCurriculumInformation>();
                            schoolCurriculumReadView =
                                SchoolCurriculumReadView.ShowSchoolCurriculumView(schoolCurriculumInformation);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            _log.Error("API Error Reason: " + response.ReasonPhrase);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception sd)
                {
                    _log.Error("Error displaying Curriculum ", sd);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _log.Info("User not logged-in.");
            }
        }
        return schoolCurriculumReadView;
    }

    private async Task<IEnumerable<MemberSchoolReadView>>  GetMemberSchools(int schoolId)
    {
        List<MemberSchoolReadView> memberSchoolReadViews = new List<MemberSchoolReadView>();
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            if (SessionToken != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (ValidateToken(client).IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        HttpResponseMessage response =
                            await client.GetAsync("api/school/memberschool/getallmemberschools/" + schoolId);

                        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        {
                            IEnumerable<MemberSchool> memberSchools = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<MemberSchool>>();
                            memberSchoolReadViews = memberSchools.Select(MemberSchoolReadView.ShowMemberSchools).ToList();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            _log.Error("API Error Reason: " + response.ReasonPhrase);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception sd)
                {
                    _log.Error("Error displaying Member Schools for School with id: " + schoolId, sd);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _log.Info("User not logged-in.");
            }
        }
        return memberSchoolReadViews;
    }

    private async Task<SchoolAddressReadView> GetSchoolAddress(int schoolId)
    {
        SchoolAddressReadView schoolAddress = null;
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            if (SessionToken != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (ValidateToken(client).IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var response = await client.GetAsync("api/school/getaddressbyschoolid/" + schoolId);
                        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        {
                            var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<SchoolAddress>();
                            schoolAddress = SchoolAddressReadView.ShowSchoolAddressView(responseContent);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception sd)
                {
                    _log.Error("Error fetching School Address ", sd);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _log.Info("User not logged-in.");
            }
        }
        return schoolAddress;
    }

    private async Task<SchoolReadView> GetSchool(int schoolId)
    {
        SchoolReadView school = null;
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            if (SessionToken != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (ValidateToken(client).IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var response = await client.GetAsync("api/getallschools/" + schoolId);
                        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        {
                            var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<School>();
                            school = SchoolReadView.ShowSchoolReadView(responseContent);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception sd)
                {
                    _log.Error("Error getting school ", sd);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _log.Info("User not logged-in.");
            }
        }
        return school;
    }

    private async Task<SchoolContactReadView> GetSchoolContact(int schoolId)
    {
        SchoolContactReadView schoolContact = null;
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            if (SessionToken != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (ValidateToken(client).IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var response = await client.GetAsync("api/school/getcontactdetails/" + User.Identity.Name);
                        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        {
                            var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<SchoolContact>();
                            schoolContact = SchoolContactReadView.ShowSchoolContactView(responseContent);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception sd)
                {
                    _log.Error("Error getting school contact ", sd);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _log.Info("User not logged-in.");
            }
        }
        return schoolContact;
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// Obtains the token from the Web API, the Session and the User Information
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="client">Client object</param>
    /// <returns>Returns an HttpResponseMessage</returns>
    private HttpResponseMessage ValidateToken(HttpClient client)
    {

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        string accessToken = (string)SessionToken;
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization
            = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

        HttpResponseMessage responseToken = client.GetAsync(baseUrl + "api/Account/UserInfo").Result;
        return responseToken;
    }
}
```

and I also have an mvc controller action consuming this method

```
Public async Task<ActionResult> Details(int id)
{
    var model = await service.GetSchoolAggreagtedInfo(id).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return View(model)
}
```

I feel like I have too much `async` methods and which I'm afraid may cause more harm than good.

Is there a better way of doing all this async stuff (maybe a pattern), or is the code OK?

Comment: I pasted the code here and was about editing it when I lost internet connection. code updated anyway. It includes the class with all it's method.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using `async` everywhere for methods which are truly asynchronous, and your usage of it is easily readable. One complaint is fragility due to dependencies. You access `HttpContext` and `AppSettings` from a class that should have no awareness of them. This class would be a lot more robust if it used dependency injection. The constructor should accept an instance of `IPrincipal`, `ILog`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots of *very* cool stuff in there.

But, there's also some bad stuff. You are significantly arrow-coded in some places.

One of the changes you should make is your guard clauses. Most explicitly, in this method:

> ```
> private async Task<OrganizationContactReadView> GetOrganizationContact(int organizationId)
> {
>     OrganizationContactReadView organizationContact = null;
>
>     using (var client = new HttpClient())
>     {
>         if (SessionToken != null)
>         {
>             try
>             {
>                 if (ValidateToken(client).IsSuccessStatusCode)
>                 {
>                     HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/organization/contact/" + organizationId);
>                     if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
>                     {
>                         var contentResult = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<OrganizationContact>();
>                         var organizationContactReadView = OrganizationContactReadView.MapFrom(contentResult);
>
>                         organizationContact = organizationContactReadView;
>                     }
>                     else
>                     {
>                         _log.Error("API Error Reason: " + response.ReasonPhrase);
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>             catch (Exception sd)
>             {
>                 _log.Error("Error displaying Organization Contact Information ", sd);
>             }
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             _log.Info("User not logged-in.");
>         }
>     }
>
>     return organizationContact;
> }
> ```

Let's look at what we can improve here.

First, we notice that if `SessionToken != null` then things cannot really happen here. So, let's move that to the top of the file.

```
if (SessionToken == null)
{
    _log.Info("User not logged-in.");
    // Throw an exception, maybe? If not, return null;
}
```

So, now we get rid of some of the arrow.

Next, I would do something like:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    if (!ValidateToken(client).IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        // Throw an exception most likely, or return null;
    }

    // We know at this point two things are true: the `SessionToken` is good, and so is `ValidateToken(client)`.

    try
    {
        // This string format on the next line is C#6.0.
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync($"api/organization/contact/{organizationId}");

        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            _log.Error($"API Error Reason: {response.ReasonPhrase}");
            // Throw an exception, return null, whatever.
        }

        var contextResult = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<OrganizationContact>();
        var organizationContactReadView = OrganizationContactReadView.MapFrom(contentResult);

        organizationContact = organizationContactReadView;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _log.Error("Error displaying Organization Contact Information ", ex);
    }
}
```

Obviously both pieces need put together.

You can do similar things with your methods that smell like arrow-code. (This is a pun on Code-Smell, if anyone missed it.)

---

If you are going to prefix one field name with an underscore, you should prefix *all* field names with underscores.

I.e. refactor `private static string baseUrl` to `private static string _baseUrl`.

---

I would recommend creating an interface to hold common elements between the `OrganizationContactReadView`, `OrganizationAssociationReadView` and `OrganizationReadView`.

This will allow you to abstract out a little further, and create actual responsibility separations.